# Filestack - Does the file picker allow languages other than english?

Tags: file, internationalization, image-uploading

I am writing a Javascript application for watermarking a photo. I want to know if the Filestack file picker supports languages other than English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Filepicker you can specify language in the 'lang' parameter of the pick function.

In order to make Spanish the default language for a picker you could use the following:

```
client.pick({
      lang: 'es'
})
```

More languages are listed on the documentation https://www.filestack.com/docs/javascript-api/pick-v3

Answer (score 0):

I was working for German Language, You can do this.

```
filepicker.picker({lang: "de"}).open()
```

with this your modal will look like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OJpO.png)